# Why can I not download files from some sites like this?

Tags: php

This is my php source code:

```
<?php
    $path = '/images/one.jpg';
    $imm = 'http://www.allamoda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/calzedonia_290x435.jpg';
    if( $content = file_get_contents($imm) ){   
    file_put_contents($path, $content);   
    echo "Yes";
    }else{
    echo "No";
    }
?>
```

and I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.allamoda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/calzedonia_290x435.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/down.php on line 4
No
```

Why ?

Comment: The remote server is configured not to respond to all requests. Most likely it might block depending on PHPs default `user_agent`, or absence of other request headers.

Comment: Can you access this file in your browser? It seems that you don't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

There are some headers expected by the server(especially **Accept** and **User-Agent**). Use the `stream_context` -argument of `file_get_contents()` to provide them:

```
<?php
$path = '/images/one.jpg';
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Accept:image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5 \r\n".
              "Host: www.allamoda.eu\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0\r\n"
  )
);

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $imm = 'http://www.allamoda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/calzedonia_290x435.jpg';
    if( $content = file_get_contents($imm,false,$context) ){   

    file_put_contents($path, $content);   
    echo "Yes";

    }else{
    echo "No";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to download this file, the server [allamoda.eu](http://allamoda.eu) says (HTTP 403).

Comment: Other sites like pinterest can download this file. Why ?

Comment: Probably you tried it already a lot of times and it is forbidden to capture images from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code. The server simply is not letting you (either you have too much requests to it, or it just blocks all scripts scraping it).

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to open the file directly. But you can try to fetch it's content by using sockets:

```
function getRemoteFile($url)
{
   // get the host name and url path
   $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
   $host = $parsedUrl['host'];
   if (isset($parsedUrl['path'])) {
      $path = $parsedUrl['path'];
   } else {
      // the url is pointing to the host like http://www.mysite.com
      $path = '/';
   }

   if (isset($parsedUrl['query'])) {
      $path .= '?' . $parsedUrl['query'];
   } 

   if (isset($parsedUrl['port'])) {
      $port = $parsedUrl['port'];
   } else {
      // most sites use port 80
      $port = '80';
   }

   $timeout = 10;
   $response = '';
   // connect to the remote server 
   $fp = @fsockopen($host, '80', $errno, $errstr, $timeout );

   if( !$fp ) { 
      echo "Cannot retrieve $url";
   } else {
      // send the necessary headers to get the file 
      fputs($fp, "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n" .
                 "Host: $host\r\n" .
                 "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3\r\n" .
                 "Accept: */*\r\n" .
                 "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n" .
                 "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n" .
                 "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n" .
                 "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" .
                 "Referer: http://$host\r\n\r\n");

      // retrieve the response from the remote server 
      while ( $line = fread( $fp, 4096 ) ) { 
         $response .= $line;
      }

      fclose( $fp );

      // strip the headers
      $pos      = strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n");
      $response = substr($response, $pos + 4);
   }

   // return the file content 
   return $response;
}
```

Example:

```
$content = getRemoteFile('http://www.allamoda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/calzedonia_290x435.jpg');
```

[Source](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx)